# Making compilation-error-regexp-alist buffer or project local

Tags: hooks, compilation-mode

How can limit the `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to a subset depending on `default-directory` or even better `(project-current)`?

My motive is that my `compilation-error-regexp-alist` contains too many elements to make compilation diagnostics performance bearable.

Is `compilation-mode-hook`, `compilation-minor-mode-hook` or `compilation-start-hook` the most suitable hook in which to adjust the value of `compilation-error-regexp-alist`? Moreover, I presume I should also make its value in the compilation buffer local via

```
(make-local-variable 'compilation-error-regexp-alist)
```

Is that correct?